# how to make multiple timeframe ichimoku indicator in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I working with the ichimoku strategy would like to show kumos from different timeframes on the same chart. what is the smartest way to do that?
I figured out how to make 2 ema's with different time frames using the [How To Avoid Repainting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGTxi6tuizM&list=RDCMUC1QOuvOFsf3YvF64ritAoeg&start_radio=1) and [Using The Security Function & Higher Timeframe Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpCXrqc7dWQ&t=947s)

however, I can't figure out how to use the same technique to make the ichimoku cloud. any ideas?

```
//@version=5




indicator('Lesson 9 multi time frames, no repaint ', overlay=true)

// what data should i feed it? 
Midpoint(src,len,) =>
    math.avg(ta.highest(src, len), ta.lowest(src, len))


res = input.timeframe(title='Timeframe', defval='D')

// Create non-repainting security function
rp_function(_symbol, _res, _src) =>
    request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])

// Get higher timeframe data not the data i need. (from video)
htfHigh = rp_function(syminfo.tickerid, res, high)
htfLow = rp_function(syminfo.tickerid, res, low)
// just plotting some higher time frame
plot(htfHigh, color=color.new(color.red, 0), title='HTF high')
plot(htfLow, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), title='HTF low')


// ichimoku daily

D_TK = Midpoint(source, 9)
D_KJ = Midpoint(source,26)
D_CK = close
// senkou a and b
D_SKA = math.avg(TK, KJ)
D_SKB = Midpoint(52)
```

Any ideas are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Used the Ichimoku indicator code from TV itself and modified it as below and it works:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Ichimoku Cloud with the required TF", shorttitle="Ichimoku", overlay=true)

close_req_tf = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '240', close)
use_price = close_req_tf

conversionPeriods = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Conversion Line Length")
basePeriods = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Base Line Length")
laggingSpan2Periods = input.int(52, minval=1, title="Leading Span B Length")
displacement = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Lagging Span")

donchian(len) => math.avg(ta.lowest(use_price, len), ta.highest(use_price, len))

conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)
leadLine1 = math.avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
leadLine2 = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)

plot(conversionLine, color=#2962FF, title="Conversion Line")
plot(baseLine, color=#B71C1C, title="Base Line")
plot(close, offset = -displacement + 1, color=#43A047, title="Lagging Span")
p1 = plot(leadLine1, offset = displacement - 1, color=#A5D6A7,
     title="Leading Span A")
p2 = plot(leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, color=#EF9A9A,
     title="Leading Span B")
plot(leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? leadLine1 : leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, title = "Kumo Cloud Upper Line", display = display.none) 
plot(leadLine1 < leadLine2 ? leadLine1 : leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, title = "Kumo Cloud Lower Line", display = display.none) 
fill(p1, p2, color = leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? color.rgb(67, 160, 71, 90) : color.rgb(244, 67, 54, 90))
```